# django-facebook api No module named 'django.conf.urls.defaults'

Tags: python, django, facebook, api, django-facebook

I installed django_facebook (django-facebook==6.0.3). I am using Django 1.11.

I got an error:

```
    File "path/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_facebook/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
ImportError: No module named 'django.conf.urls.defaults'
```

I was tring solved this problem with:

```
try:
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
except ImportError:
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import include, url
```

but without success.
Please for hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.conf.urls.defaults` was removed in Django 1.6, which was many years ago, and the `django-facebook` package you're using has the following message in its README (which was committed two years ago):

> Django and Facebook are both rapidly changing at the moment. Meanwhile, I'm caught up in a startup and don't have much spare time. The library needs a good round of testing against the latest python, django and facebook graph API.

Unless you're willing to dive deep into the package's code, I'd recommend looking for another solution. It sounds like the author is looking for someone to help maintain it. Good luck!